# Attempting to store to property '' within its own willSet

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, warnings

Im getting a weird warning in the editor which I need help understanding what it wants

```
Attempting to store to property 'someProperty' within its own willSet, which is about to be overwritten by the new value
```

---

```
var someProperty:SomeClass! {
    willSet { someProperty?.someFunction() } // Get warning: Attempting to store to property 'someProperty' within its own willSet, which is about to be overwritten by the new value
    didSet { ... }
}
```

When I run it it is doing what I want it to do with no crashes or warnings in console, so I see this as just a false positive. So can I suppress it in any way because its annoying? :(

Comment: What is it that you want it to do (that it is doing)?

Comment: When setting a new value I want the old one to do something before it gets replaced.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a known bug, reported in the Apple Developer Forum: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1065306#1065306, with the workaround
of adding an explicit `self`:

```
    willSet {
        self.someProperty?.someFunction()
    }
```

*Update:* I could not reproduce the issue with Xcode 7.3.1 or Xcode 8
anymore, so that seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, got that confirmed :)

Comment: No martin this bug is still there. i just reproduce this in xcode 11 and swift 5.
thanks using explicit self it's working fine...